# JavaScript RegEx - Minimum characters with Wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on matching a wildcard search input. it's a name field.
Below are the conditions I need to match.

1. User must enter at least 3 alphanumeric characters, if he chooses to do a Wildcard search
2. User may/maynot enter a wildcard at the start or end of the string,but it  can be on either side.
3. Allow spaces between words.

I want to mention that i'm trimming the string before doing a match. This is what I tried so far.

```
^[^\W_](\s?\w?)*$|^[^\W_]{3,}(\s?\w?)*\*$|^[\*][^\W_]{3,}(\s?\w?)*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/z-zaJ26ribGZ27xJ)

Below are some examples I tried -

- *someone xxx, someone xxx yyy* - Passed
- someone* xxx- Failed
- *someone , someone* - Passed

This is the nearest match of what i want- But it fail for these test case.

- AB asf* -- Fails , this will pass- ABC asf*
- *AB asf -- Fails , this will pass- *ABC asf

I know I have a condition that says - starts with at least 3 alphanumeric character and repeat space and alphanumeric characters.

That's where I need help with.

Thanks.

Comment: Why regex? A validation function should be fine here

Comment: Regex can be clean solution for these situations and I learn from them and the stackoverflow community is always there for help.

Comment: - ccf - I marked your answer as correct one. Sorry If there was some confusions in the question. I'll edit my question to add Match and Not match scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE2** This pattern should do:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}[^\n*]*\*?|\*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}[^\n*]*|[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\*)$/gm
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
^                               # assert start of line
 (                              # 1st capturing group starts         
    [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}             # match 3+ times alphanumeric characters
                  [^\n*]*       # match 0 or more non-newline and non-star (*) characters
                         \*?    # match 0 or one literal star (*) character;
  |                             # OR
    \*                          # match one literal star (*) character
      [a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}           # match 2+ times alphanumeric characters
                     [^\n*]*    # match 0 or more non-newline and non-star (*) characters;
  |                             # OR
    [a-zA-Z0-9]{2}              # match 2 non-newline and non-star (*) characters
                  \*            # match one literal star (*) character
 )                              # 1st capturing group ends       
$                               # assert end of line
```

[REGEX 101 DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/xJ8eZ4/8)

Comment: AB asf* this is what i need to match as total there are 3 characters.

Comment: But the condition is, `starts with at least 3 alphanumeric character`. So, you mean, it also include space? Also, specifically, you want `AB asf* -- Fails`, is that right?

Comment: sorry for any confusion in the question, If the user choose to enter a wild card, the number of characters should be at least 3. So AJ S* is a good example. Also AB asf* that is what is failing in my regex and I want to Pass that scenario.

Comment: thanks, seems we are pretty close, still fd c* - matches
*fd c - does not match

Comment: these should fails as If the user chooses to use the wild card search, he must enter at least 3 characters.  99*
*99
*9g
*fd

Comment: thanks for the help, it worked I made some changes to your RE, and it's working for all my scenarios. this is what I have now.                                            pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9][^\n*]*|\*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,}[^\n*]*|[a-zA-Z0-9 ]{3,}[^\n*]*\*)$/;

Comment: Nice to know you worked it out. By the way, `\n` in the pattern may not be required.

Comment: -ccf - It would be nice if you could add the details about your RE, It can be helpful to someone else. Regarding the \n, i'll check without it and update.Thanks

Comment: Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?:[^\W_]+|\*[^\W_]{3,}|[^\W_]{3,}\*)(?:\s+(?:[^\W_]+|\*[^\W_]{3,}|[^\W_]{3,}\*))*$
```

NOTE: using `[^\W_]` instead of `\w` just as in your original regex.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pQ2yV4/1)

However, I argue that this task cannot be solved in a clean way using a regex. Maybe a proper javascript function would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the requirements,
this might work. It does in my tests.

`^(?:\*[^\W_]{3,}(?:\s*[^\W_]\s*)*|(?:\s*[^\W_]\s*)*[^\W_]{3,}\*|(?:\s*[^\W_]\s*)+)$`

Expanded

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?:                           # One of either ---
      \*                            # Star at beeginning
      [^\W_]{3,}                    # 3 or more words
      (?: \s* [^\W_] \s* )*         # Any number of word's following spaces
   |                              # or,
      (?: \s* [^\W_] \s* )*         # Any number of word's following spaces
      [^\W_]{3,}                    # 3 or more words
      \*                            # Star at end
   |                              # or, 
      (?: \s* [^\W_] \s* )+         # Any number of word's following spaces
 )                             # ---------
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: this did not pass *AB Cdcv, for the user if he enters AJ S'asteric  is a valid entry as this is 3 characters

Comment: @Lucky - Did you format that correctly? This  `*AB Cdcv` doesn't (and shouldn't?) match and  `AJ S` is matched by this regex.

Comment: I think it didn't get formatted. I want to pass this scenario. *AB Cdcv, also I gave an example to clarify, if the user enters AJ S*     that should match.

Comment: sorry It is not showing asterisks, yes I want to pass that. also AJ Sasterisk should pass. Thanks

Comment: The asterisk `*` is a formatting character. Use backticks to highlight.

Comment: To qualify an asterisk at the beginning or end with at leas 3 characters in the string is a _whole_ different ballgame. You should have stated that in your post. The current examples show 3 characters adjacent as valid only.